# VBScript to pick up files with dynamic filename

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, vbscript

I have a situation where I need to consume a dynamic filename.

```
Const InputFile = "C:\Users\NTadmin\Desktop\test\sendmofd_20140220010352.txt"
```

The above piece of code is part of a huge program (VBscript). 
The `20140220010352` part of the filename is a timestamp and not a constant.
I now understand `"sendmofd_*.txt"` doesn't work like it does in other non VB codes!!

Any possible workaround is welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Sam

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: wel, to be a bit more clear files of file name sendmofd_* keep coming in to this folder. * being the timestamp. How do I extract the filenames ??

Comment: What is the language you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the .Files collection and filter the names - perhaps using a regular expression - until the result set contains exactly one (or zero) file(s). To come up with a filter, a representative sample of the file names would be helpful.

You also can shell out to `dir sendmofd_*.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sorry, Im a newbie to VB world. If you dont mind, could you pl brief what you mean by 'shell out to dir sendmofd_*.txt' 'd be really helpful. Thanks